# How to Pass QueryString in MVC WEBAPI routing for the following URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having the following URL. When i enter this url in the browser by passing values i cant access the api method which is in my applcation. I am new to MVC. i am not sure whether we can pass QueryString In MVC WebApi Routing.If Possible, please help to pass the QueryString in MVC WebAPI routing.

```
http://localhost:1665/api/Load/LoadDetails?ID={1}&Latitude={2}&Longitude={3}&Uncertaint
y={4}&Street1={5}&Street2={6}&Neighborhood={7}&Ci&LocationDateTimeUTC={12}
```

In the routeconfig i have following code,

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id:int}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes(config);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

In ApiController

```
       [RoutePrefix("Load")]
        public class LoadController : ApiController
        {
        #region RESTful Methods

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize()]     
        [Route("saveintransitcheckcall/{ID}/{Latitude}/{Longitude}/{Uncertainty}/{Street1}/{Street2}/{Neighborhood}/{City}/{State}/{Postal}/{Country}/")]
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveInTransitCheckCall(int ID)
        {}
```

Please help to access the method. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters by querystring parameters like below url:

```
http://localhost:1665/api/Load/LoadDetails?ID={1}&Latitude={2}&Longitude={3}&Uncertaint
y={4}&Street1={5}&Street2={6}&Neighborhood={7}&Ci&LocationDateTimeUTC={12}
```

then use below code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize()] 
[Route("saveintransitcheckcall")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveInTransitCheckCall()
{
  var queryString = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

  var ID = queryString.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ID").Value;
  var Latitude = queryString.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Latitude").Value;
  //read other variables like above


  //do your remaining code here
}
```

else you can try below code with RESTful method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize()]     
[Route("saveintransitcheckcall/{ID:int}/{Latitude:decimal}/{Longitude:decimal}/{Uncertainty}/{Street1}/{Street2}/{Neighborhood}/{City}/{State}/{Postal}/{Country}/")]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveInTransitCheckCall(int ID, decimal Latitude, decimal Longitude, string Uncertainty, string Street1, string Street2, string Neighborhood, string City, string State, string Postal, string country)
{
  //do your remaining code here
}
```

Please let me know, is this works for you?

Comment: Yes Rohit. I actually tried the second option and worked for me.  in Route, if provide the type of parameter like {Latitude:decimal} , it actually provided some error. so, I just removed all the parameter from route and i simply added [Route("saveintransitcheckcall/")] like this and added all the parameter in the function signature like SaveInTransitCheckCall(int ID, decimal Latitude, decimal Longitude, string Uncertainty, string Street1, string Street2, string Neighborhood, string City, string State, string Postal, string country). thanks for the Help.

Comment: @Vignesh you can remove :decimal from {Latitude:decimal} so it will be like  {Latitude}. This will also work for you with REST ful API.